# Is the independence of increments in Brownian motion a trivial consequence of other properties?

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, independence

Standard Brownian motion $W(t)$ is usually defined with 4 following statements:

1. $W(t) =0.$
2. For any $t < T$ the random variable $W(T) - W(t)\sim N(0, T-t)$, e.g. it's normal
3. For any $0<t_{1}<...<t_{n}$ increments $W(t_{i}) - W(t_{i-1})$ are independent random variables.
4. the function $W(t)$ is continuous.

Surely condition 3) is redundant as it's a consequence of 2) ? We can consider 3 arbitrary times $t_{1}<t_{2}<t_{3}<t{_n}$ and observe that:

$W(t_{3}) - W(t_{2})\sim N(0, t_{3} - t_{2})$ and $W(t_{2}) - W(t_{1})\sim N(0, t_{2} - t_{1})$.

They are both normal variables with zero mean and variance which only depends on the "end points" of the time increments, not the intermediate values, hence trivially the distribution of $W(t_{3}) - W(t_{2})$ has no relevance to distribution of $W(t_{2}) - W(t_{1})$...

And surely this immediately extends to Brownian motion with drift too?

So why do we require 3) ? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: But why do you think the condition you described implies independence? (Non-correlatedness ok, but why independence?)

Comment: I don't know - that's why I am asking... is independence an assumption for Brownian motion definition, or must it be proved from some other considerations? @kolobokish

Comment: Secondly, a kind of separate but related question... Assuming independence of standard Brownian motion increments, does it follow then that Brownian motion with drift has independent increments? (I.E. a functions of independent random variables are independent?) @kolobokish

Comment: Yes. Increments in the case with drift are indeed independent. Meaning that $W(t_3) - W_(t_2)$ is independent of $W(t_2) - W(t_1)$, but $W(t_3) - W(t_2)$ is not independent of $W(t_2)$ itself. (And one more thing), the increments are already not of the same distribution.

Comment: I understand that independence of increments for drift case follows from the fact that functions of independent random variables are also independent, right? How does this work for Ornstein Uhlenbeck process, for example, which doesn't have independent increments but is a function of Brownian motion? @kolobokish

Comment: That's is really a good one. OU is mainly given in its differential form, relating increments of the process to the increments of Brownian motion. So yes, it is a function of Brownian motion. But note $f(W_{t_3}) - f(W_{t_3})$ may be not independent of $f(W_{t_2})- f(W_{t_1})$, though it is surely independent of $f(W_{t_2} - W_{t_1})$. (So when you apply a function to process and then take the increment it can become dependent, though it is independent of function applied to difference for previous time interval).

Comment: Fortunately for the case with drift function of difference is same (in its stochastic part) as difference of function.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there's a typo ( wrong subscript $3$ instead of $2$) in your  comment above- do you mean $f(W_{t_{3}}) - f(W_{t_{2}})$, rather than $f(W_{t_{3}}) - f(W_{t_{3}})$ ? @kolobokish

Comment: Yes , maybe. Let me do it one more time. The increments of process are described $f(W_{t_3}) - f(W_{t_2})$. While this increment is not independent of $f(W_{t_2}) - f(W_{t_1})$, the following are independent ($f(W_{t_3}) - W_{t_2})$ and $f(W_{t_2} - W_{t_1})$)

Comment: Ok, so in general the result that independence of functions of random variables follows from independence of random variables themselves, is not applicable to increments of stochastic processes? @kolobokish

Comment: No, you probably get it wrong. We know that $W_{t_3} - W_{t_2}$ is independent of $W_{t_2} - W_{t_1}$, so $f(W_{t_3} - W_{t_2})$ and $g(W_{t_2} - W_{t_1})$ are indeed independent.  But the increments of process are not $f(W_{t_3} - W_{t_2})$  and $f(W_{t_2} - W_{t_1})$ , but rather $f(W_{t_3}) - f(W_{t_2})$ and $f(W_{t_2}) - f(W_{t_1})$ which are not independent.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comments. @kolobokish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the argument you noted $$W(t_3) - W(t_2) \sim N(0 , t_3 - t_2)$$ and $$W(t_2) - W(t_1) \sim N(0, t_2 - t_1)$$.
So we have two normally distributed random variables. We can note that their sum is distributed normal with variance parameter equal to sum of the variances of each term by 2) condition. (Meaning that $t_3 - t_1 = t_3 - t_2 + t_2 - t_1$). Which means that their correlation ($\rho (W(t_3) - W(t_2), W(t_2) - W(t_1))$) should be zero.
(As sum of two normals is also normal but with the variance including correlation).

So they are uncorrelated.

But uncorrelatedness (even for normally distributed random variables), does not imply independence.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

But if we had that $(W(t_3) - W(t_2), W(t_2) - W(t_1))$ were jointly normal (meaning that every linear combination of them were normal), the uncorrelatedness would imply independence.

So, not straightly, but the third condition implies that $(W(t_3) - W(t_2), W(t_2) - W(t_1))$ are jointly Gaussian.

Which is a desirable condition as it is the same as finite dimensional distribution is normal.

I hope I was helpful. (Sorry for posting this as answer. I just always write in informal manner).

Answer (score 1):

It is a part of the definition not a consequence.
You are confusing the following two statements: (a). the laws of $W_{t_3}-W_{t_2}$ and $W_{t_2}-W_{t_1}$ have laws that depend only on the time increment, i.e. $t_3-t_2$ and $t_2-t_1$, respectively and (b). $W_{t_3}-W_{t_2}$ and $W_{t_2}-W_{t_1}$ are independent as random variables.

The first is statement about laws and the second has to do with their joint laws; the two properties have almost nothing do with each other. Two random variables having the same or related laws does not mean they are independent.

Comment: Thank you. Does it follow that any functions of $W(t_{3}) - W(t_{2})$ and $W(t_{2}) - W(t_{1})$ are also independent random variables? If yes, doesn't that contradict Ornstein - Uhlenbeck process where increments are not independent? @almosteverywhere

Comment: Are you asking if $f(W_{t_3}-W_{t_2})$ and $g(W_{t_2}-W_{t_1})$  are independent for functions $f,g$?

Comment: Yes I am - Ornstein Uhlenbeck can be written as a function $f$ of $W$, from what I can see. (Here we take $f = g$ ) @almosteverywhere

Comment: Functions of independent random variables are independent. I am not sure how this applies to OU. OU is a function of $W$. But disjoint increments of OU are not functions of the corresponding disjoint increments of $W$

Comment: Thanks. @almosteverywhere

Comment: do you need any more help with your question?

Comment: Thank you, but I think I understood everything I need for now @almosteverywhere

Comment: It is common practice to accept the answer you find most useful then. Either mine or that of @kolobokish